# Mathematica can't, or won't evaluate an integral (again)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm relatively new to Mathematica and really need some help here to spot what's going wrong with my integration issues; Mathematica doesn't evaluate my integral, after a fair amount of time running, the code, it produces the input as the output. (You may remember that I had an issue with integration beforehand, but the issue this time is certainly not the same!). I've slammed my head into the screen of this computer for quite a while now and have error checked this thing as much as I can!

Here's the code, any advice or help anyone to give is greatly appreciated!!

```
U[z_, a_, b_, c_, u_, z0_] :=
-(1/(2 u)) E^(-a z^b + 0.5` (z^2 + Log[z/z0])) z^c ((-1 + c) c E^(-a z^b + 0.5` (z^2 + Log[z/z0])) z^(-2 + c) + 2 c E^(-a z^b + 0.5` (z^2 + Log[z/z0]))z^(-1 + c) (-a b z^(-1 + b) + 0.5` (1/z + 2 z)) + z^c (E^(-a z^b + 0.5` (z^2 + Log[z/z0])) (0.5` (2 - 1/z^2) - a (-1 + b) b z^(-2 + b)) + E^(-a z^b + 0.5` (z^2 + Log[z/z0])) (-a b z^(-1 + b) + 0.5` (1/z + 2 z))^2)) ((2^((1 + 2 c)/b) a^((1 + 2 c)/b) b)/ Gamma[(1 + 2 c)/b])^1.`

Integrate[U[z, a, b, c, u, z0], {z, z0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {a, b, c, z0, u} \[Element] Reals && {a, b, c, u} > 0]
```

I feel like I may have pushed Mathematica too far with a function that maybe it just can't integrate. If this is the case, any advice around this would also be appreciated!!

Thanks!!!

EDIT:

Mathematica output:

```
Integrate[-((E^(-a z^b + 0.5 (z^2 + Log[z/z0])) z^c ((-1 + c) c E^(-a z^b + 0.5 (z^2 + Log[z/z0])) z^(-2 + c) + 2 c E^(-a z^b + 0.5 (z^2 + Log[z/z0]))z^(-1 + c) (-a b z^(-1 + b) + 0.5 (1/z + 2 z)) + z^c (E^(-a z^b + 0.5 (z^2 + Log[z/z0])) (0.5 (2 - 1/z^2) - a (-1 + b) b z^(-2 + b)) + E^(-a z^b + 0.5 (z^2 + Log[z/z0])) (-a b z^(-1 + b) + 0.5 (1/z + 2 z))^2)) ((2^((1 + 2 c)/b) a^((1 + 2 c)/b) b)/Gamma[(1 + 2 c)/b])^1.)/(2 u)), {z, z0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> (a | b | c | z0 | u) \[Element] Reals && {a, b, c, u} > 0]
```

Comment: First off the error message would be a useful thing for us to see. If by E^() you mean the exponential function you need to change it to Mathematica's notation Exp[].

Comment: Oh okay, the error message isn't really an error, it's just the Input, but I'll add it anyway :)

Comment: I have defined my Exponentials as Exp[], but for some reason when I C+P here it changes it

Comment: If you can simplify your integral by hand before putting it into Mathematica that always helps, and you should try to do that. Also, if this is for analysis and you know {a,b,z,z0,u}, another option is use those values and then do Numerical Integration (NIntegrate).

Comment: I'll try simplification. In regards to using Numerical integration, the issue is that this integration is a step in variational method, where the constants a and b are unknown, and I then minimize the resulting equation to find their values. The only known value in this case is u. And I think that means that NIntegrate is out of the question, correct me if I'm wrong anywhere here since that's very possible!! Do you think this is an issue with the function being way too complex? Would Mathematica give some kind of error response if it couldn't do an integral?

Comment: Yes it probably is too complicated, which is why I suggest simplifying it. As far as I know if Mathematica can't "do" an integral it just returns the input. You could possibly use NIntegrate even as a minimization, loop over lots of values and find the smallest. But I recommend stepping back and thinking more about the problem before going with that sort of brute force, especially because you have 5 parameters

Comment: Okay, I'll look into simplifying it, and attempting NIntegrate. I'll have a think about other routes, but I have to approach this problem in this manner, as the functions and constants produced with brute force, lead to the second, and final step in the variational method I'm using.